# infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm learning AngularJs but I cant make it works.
I read about the digest cycle but it is not clear for me.
It's obvious that this code fails because enter in a infinite loop, but I dont know how to fix it.
Could someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" ng-app="test">
<head>
  <title>Learning Angular</title>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute']);

    app.factory('visitCounterService', function () {
      var counterService = function() {
        var _count = 1;

        var counter = function() { return _count++; };

        return { counter: counter }
      }();

      return counterService;
    });

    app.service('homeModel', ['visitCounterService', function(visitCounterService){
      this.getTitle = function() {
        var n = visitCounterService.counter();
        return "Welcome to this awesome demo. You are the visitor n° " + n;
      };

    }]);

    app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'homeModel', function($scope, homeModel) {
      $scope.home = homeModel;
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeController">
  <h3>{{home.getTitle()}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thanks in advice!!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular registers an implicit $watch on the `home.getTitle()` expression. This expression will get called at least twice because angular wants to check if the model has stabilized.

Your code returns a different string everytime `home.getTitle()` is called so angular continues digesting until it reaches the max digest cycles limit.

Try:

```
$scope.homeTitle = homeModel.getTitle();
```

and

```
<h3>{{homeTitle}}</h3>
```